# Strange behaviour when close the lid of my MBA

Tags: laptop, power-management, suspend, hibernate, macbook-air

I have an MBA and I'm used to close the lid without any problem in OSX.

I've installed ubuntu 13.04 in dual boot with rEFit.

The problem is that sometimes something strange happens when I close the lid, today for example I closed it for lunch break and when I came back to work the laptop was on (the lid still closed), very hot with the fan at high speed.

What can I do to have a robust suspend on lid closure?
Is the hibernate option better?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

My "When the lid is closed" option is already on "Suspend", so I suppose that the suspension doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoul go to **System Settings** > **Power**. There you can set laptop to suspend, hibernate, or do nothing when the lid is closed:

[image]

To enable hibernate in Ubuntu, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch a terminal, then run this command to create a hibernate policy file:

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla
```

Then copy and paste following into the file and save.

```
[Enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Need to restart to take effect.

If you want the laptop shutting down when the lid is closed, first install `dconf-tools`:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then launch **Dconf-Editor** from the **Dash**, navigate to **org** > **gnome** > **settings-daemon** > **plugins** > **power**. Change the value of `lid-close-battery-action` to *Shutdown* (or any value desired). Actually, when you change the settings in **Power** (see previous picture), it automatically changes the value at this point:

[image]

Also, you can read and try [Fix Ubuntu (or Linux) Suspend/Hibernate Not Working Bug](http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug).

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't mention that I already set "When the lid is closed" to "Suspend".
The problem that it does not suspend correctly remains

Comment: I don't want the laptop to shutdown, I want to suspend it!
But I would like that if I tell it to suspend it would suspend really!
I don't want to take out the previously suspended laptop from my rucksack and find it on and very hot with the lid closed!

Comment: @Michele I just edited my answer. Try the fix from the link.

Comment: Source: http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-set-the-laptop-lid-close-action-in-ubuntu-12-04